# Error while running the ASP.NET Core WebApp on Docker in Windows 7 (Debugging)

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, docker-toolbox

I am trying to run the asp.net core app on docker in windows 7. I have Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise (Update 3) and Visual Studio Tools for Docker installed. Also, I am able to run the application in Release configuration.

I have not done any changes to the Dockerfile and compose files, those are default which are created when I created the project and added the Docker Support.

When I am running the application with Debug configuration, I am getting the below error and it is not running any docker containers to run and debug the application:

```
Error   MSB4018 The "PrepareForLaunch" task failed unexpectedly.
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to validate volume mapping. For troubleshooting, follow instructions from http://aka.ms/DockerToolsTroubleshooting
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Docker.BuildTasks.PrepareForLaunch.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Docker.BuildTasks.DockerBaseTask.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext() SampleCoreApp   C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Publishing\ImportAfter\Microsoft.DotNet.Docker.targets  70
```

Any help or lead solving this issue will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is because of some problem with drive mapping here. So, I have removed one of the drive mapping (- .:/app) and also changed the source argument (obj/Docker/empty to .) in the docker-compose.dev.debug.yml file and it worked for me.

Previous file (docker-compose.dev.debug.yml):

```
version: '2'

services:
samplecoreapp:
    build:
    args:
        source: obj/Docker/empty
    labels:
    - "com.microsoft.visualstudio.targetoperatingsystem=linux"
    environment:
    - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
    - DOTNET_USE_POLLING_FILE_WATCHER=1
    volumes:
    - .:/app
    - ~/.nuget/packages:/root/.nuget/packages:ro
    - ~/clrdbg:/clrdbg:ro
    entrypoint: tail -f /dev/null
```

After modification:

```
version: '2'

services:
samplecoreapp:
    build:
    args:
        source: .
    labels:
    - "com.microsoft.visualstudio.targetoperatingsystem=linux"
    environment:
    - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
    - DOTNET_USE_POLLING_FILE_WATCHER=1
    volumes:
    - ~/.nuget/packages:/root/.nuget/packages:ro
    - ~/clrdbg:/clrdbg:ro
    entrypoint: tail -f /dev/null
```

Hope this will be helpful for those who are facing this issue.

Answer (score -1):

This may be due to a Drive Share/volume mounting issue in Docker, I came across this exact issue and fixed from Docker settings. This happened to appear in machines connected to corporate domain where docker has limited permissions by default. Appropriate workaround for this is update your "Shared Drives" from Docker Settings.

[Update shared drives](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DjPi.png)

further details can be found here https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/stevelasker/2016/06/14/configuring-docker-for-windows-volumes/

Comment: What must i do, when i will work with Windows 10 Container?